# Clicar no botão e mudar a cor de fundo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa tarde, Eu estou desenvolvendo 1 jogo em Meteor, e por exemplo quando clico para escolher a personagem  queria que o fundo fica-se verde, e caso escolhe-se outra personagem o fundo voltaria ao normal e a nova personagem selecionada ficaria a verde.  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
  .archer{
        background: transparent;
        background-image: url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/draconisimmortalistalos/images/9/98/A_Drolops_Archer.png/revision/latest?cb=20120528064825");
        background-size:cover;
        border: none;
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
    }

    .warrior{
        background: transparent;
        background-image: url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/eligium-brasil/images/1/10/Eligium-guerreiro.png/revision/latest?cb=20121102160221&path-prefix=pt-br");
        background-size:cover;
        border: none;
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
    }

    .mage{
        background: transparent;
        background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ab/6e/d0/ab6ed09d2e09c229c3bc6027a1c19470.jpg");
        background-size:cover;
        border: none;
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
    }

.archer:active{
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.warrior:active{
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.mage:active{
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

Comment: É bom postar o código porque isso pode ser feito de muitas maneiras, tanto com JS quanto com apenas CSS.

Comment: da para fazer so com css?

Comment: Dá sim. Posta o código do botão.

Comment: Já postei o codigo que tenho para os butoes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vê se fica alguma dúvida

```js
var verde1 = document.getElementById("selecao-1");
var verde2 = document.getElementById("selecao-2");
var verde3 = document.getElementById("selecao-3");

verde1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
verde1.style.backgroundColor  = 'green';
  verde2.style.backgroundColor  = 'transparent';
  verde3.style.backgroundColor  = 'transparent';
})


verde2.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 verde1.style.backgroundColor  = 'transparent';
  verde2.style.backgroundColor  = 'green';
  verde3.style.backgroundColor  = 'transparent';
})

verde3.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 verde1.style.backgroundColor  = 'transparent';
  verde2.style.backgroundColor  = 'transparent';
  verde3.style.backgroundColor  = 'green';
})
```

```css
.hide{
display:hide;
}

#selecao-1{
  
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
}
#selecao-2{

  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
}
#selecao-3{

  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="selecao-1" class=''></div>
<div id="selecao-2" ></div>
<div id="selecao-3" ></div>
```

Comment: ajudou bastante, obrigado

Comment: @Roberto Fico contente em ajudar! Qualquer dúvida me avise

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar o atributo `tabindex` nas `div`s e no CSS usar a pseudo-classe `:focus`:

```css
.archer{
    background: transparent;
    background-image: url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/draconisimmortalistalos/images/9/98/A_Drolops_Archer.png/revision/latest?cb=20120528064825");
    background-size:cover;
    border: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.warrior{
    background: transparent;
    background-image: url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/eligium-brasil/images/1/10/Eligium-guerreiro.png/revision/latest?cb=20121102160221&path-prefix=pt-br");
    background-size:cover;
    border: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.mage{
    background: transparent;
    background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ab/6e/d0/ab6ed09d2e09c229c3bc6027a1c19470.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    border: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.archer:focus,
.warrior:focus,
.mage:focus{
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="1" class="archer">
</div>
<div tabindex="2" class="warrior">
</div>
<div tabindex="3" class="mage">
</div>
```

Comment: é uma boa solução mas nao dava para o que eu pretendia, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma classe `.ativo` com o fundo verde e adicionar ao elemento clicado, usando um `eventListener` para cada um.

Adicione uma classe comum `.personagem` para cada `div`:

```
<div class="personagem archer">
</div>
<div class="personagem warrior">
</div>
<div class="personagem mage">
</div>
```

E o CSS:

```
.personagem.ativo{
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

E o script que fará a aplicação do fundo verde adicionando a classe `.ativo`:

```
var persons = document.querySelectorAll(".personagem");
var person;
for(var x=0; x<persons.length; x++){
   persons[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.classList.add("ativo");
      if(person && person != this) person.classList.remove("ativo");
      person = this;
   });
}
```

**Veja funcionando:**

```js
var persons = document.querySelectorAll(".personagem");
var person;
for(var x=0; x<persons.length; x++){
   persons[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.classList.add("ativo");
      if(person && person != this) person.classList.remove("ativo");
      person = this;
   });
}
```

```css
.archer{
    background: transparent;
    background-image: url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/draconisimmortalistalos/images/9/98/A_Drolops_Archer.png/revision/latest?cb=20120528064825");
    background-size:cover;
    border: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.warrior{
    background: transparent;
    background-image: url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/eligium-brasil/images/1/10/Eligium-guerreiro.png/revision/latest?cb=20121102160221&path-prefix=pt-br");
    background-size:cover;
    border: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.mage{
    background: transparent;
    background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ab/6e/d0/ab6ed09d2e09c229c3bc6027a1c19470.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    border: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.personagem.ativo{
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="personagem archer">
</div>
<div class="personagem warrior">
</div>
<div class="personagem mage">
</div>
```